# Will GC collect object a and b if they only have reference to each other?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Will GC collect object a and b if they only have reference to each other? Can you help explain the reason or give a referece doc to explain that logic. Thanks much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes they will be candidate to GC if no more strong references to it exist.

> It's important to note that not just any strong reference will hold an object in memory. **These must be references that chain from a garbage collection root**. GC roots are a special class of variable that includes :

- Temporary variables on the stack (of any thread)
- Static variables (from any class)
- Special references from JNI native code

See this documentation [(§ A.3.4 Unreachable and §A.4.2 Example GC with WeakReference)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/performance/1st_edition/html/JPAppGC.fm.html)

Answer (score 4):

If objects a and b referencing each other and are not interfering the other objects, they form an **isolated island of objects**. This kind of groups are also collected by the garbage collector. Take a look at [this thread.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/268946/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/GC-Islands-Isolation)